# Replacing InternalSimpleValue constructor in ElasticSearch version 7

Tags: java, elasticsearch, backwards-compatibility, elasticsearch-aggregation

I am migrating ElasticSearch Java code from 5.6 to 7.7.
The constructor for *InternalSimpleValue* has been refactored from public  to protected access. Perhaps Elastic are intentionally non-backward compatible.

Just wondering if there is a known replacement or workaround for this?
Other 5.6 code have alternative 7.7 classes that can be used but seemingly this approach hasn't been applied in the case of the *InternalSimpleValue* constructor.

Here is a code snippet of the 5.6 version.

```
import org.elasticsearch.search.aggregations.pipeline.InternalSimpleValue;

@Override
public final SearchResponse execute(HttpServletRequest httpRequest, TemplateRequest request,     SearchResponse response) {
SearchResponse ret = response;
    Aggregations aggregations = response.getAggregations();
    if (null != aggregations) {
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<InternalAggregation> aggs =   (List<InternalAggregation>) (List<?>) (aggregations.asList());
        // call implementation to calculate value
        Double value = buildValue(httpRequest, request, response);
        aggs.add(new InternalSimpleValue(aggregationName, value, DocValueFormat.RAW, null, null));
    ....
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The constructor was made package protected in [this commit](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/299d044bfceaf5391cda1bc19f92f8bc2cbf87ae#diff-9e95898889292f18f743fe4c4aa2844c) in October 2018 (when 7.0 came out) because [they thought too many aggregation classes were public](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/22868).

It looks like they've recently (May 2020) reverted that change in [this commit](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/commit/5e90ff32f7df6e7532cd4fa9542d57e1dcef486b#diff-9e95898889292f18f743fe4c4aa2844c) and made the constructor public again in the 7.9 branch. But unfortunately, 7.9 has not been released yet.

Comment: Thanks for that update @Val. It seemed like a bad choice on the part of elastic to make that change initially but  at least they have reverted. Since we have just gone from 5x to 7.7 I don't see us going to 7.9 anytime soon. Also I ended up not having to migrate the code in question to 7.7 at this time.